# Removing Tree Branches with C#

Tags: c#, tree

I have a `List<Leaf>` named `items` in C#. A Leaf has the following properties:

```
public class Leaf
{
  public int ID { get; set; }

  public int ParentID { get; set; }

  public bool IsFlagged { get; set; }
}
```

If a Leaf has the `IsFlagged` property set then I need to remove it from the collection of items. In addition, I need to remove all of that Leaf entity's children. I'm trying to figure out the most elegant way to write this code. Currently, I have a loop within a loop, but it seems sloppy.

Does anyone know of an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far?

Comment: What do you mean by "leaf entities children"? Isn't it supposed to be childless if it is a leaf?

Comment: @SWeko It would appear that the class is improperly named.  It should probably be called `Node`.

Comment: It’s quite unusual for tree nodes (leaves or not) to store a reference of their parent but not the children. Usually, you store the whole tree as a reference to the root and from there you move down to the leaves. If you want you can make it bidirectional and also give each node a pointer to the parent. Btw. I would recommend you to use actual object references, not IDs. Also note that in a tree, there is usually no distinction between roots, leaves or inner-nodes. Everything is a node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
void RemoveItAndChildren(Leaf leaf)
{
    foreach (Leaf item in items)
        if (item.ParentID == leaf.ID)
            RemoveItAndChildren(item);
    items.Remove(leaf);
}
```

And use so:

```
foreach (Leaf leaf in items)
    if (leaf.IsFlagged)
        RemoveItAndChildren(leaf);
```

**Note** that, as in a comment above, something like the following might be more appropriate:

```
public class Leaf2
{
    List<Leaf2> Children;
    bool IsFlagged { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Servy Yup. And that's exactly what my code does. (And notice it removes the children first so as not to loose _their_ children.)

Comment: Right, missed that.  Note that this is a particularly inefficient solution as you are iterating the list many times in a nested fashion.

Comment: But, what if you have a tree five levels deep and a leaf is on the third level? That's where I have problems. This solution only addresses the top level.

Comment: @JQueryMobile Since it seems from your question that _all_ of the Leaf's are in one large List - This code will not miss any Leaf regardless of what level it is. - The code (in: "And use so:") goes through _all_ of the Leaf's.

Answer (score 0):

Most reasonable (and probably "the most elegant") way of dealing with tree is to store it as a tree, not an array/list. In this case you'll not need to deal with walking elements to try to find all children.

Note that depending on your actual requirements tree may not be best data structure, but for removing node with all children nodes it would be hard to beat regular tree.